# how to load more than 20 thousand from mysql to datatable in vb.net without fatal error encountered during data read

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to load more than 20,000 records from MySQL to the Datatable in vb.net, but I got an error (fatal error encountered during data read), although I don't get the same error when I use the same SQL statement to get the data with "Where condition" to get fewer data and indeed I get about 6000 records without any problem or error, as I googled about the problem I found some expected solution like:

- set net_write_timeout=99999
- set net_read_timeout=99999

I changed them from variables of MySql but the error still, and in my connection string I set the Connect Timeout=500;

is there any suggestion about my issue? and how I can use (set net_write_timeout=99999) directly in my SQL statement that I use to get the data?

my SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT 
    IF (@acc = d.RegdAccID, @ss, @ss := 0) AS x1,
    (select (@s := @s + 1)) AS xCounter,
    d.RegDate AS xDate, 
    d.AccName AS xAccName,
    IF (CAST(@ss := @ss + (d.RegdM2-d.RegdD2) AS DECIMAL(15,2))
                                   <> d.RegdMtbkRaseed AND d.RegdMtbkStatus='Yes',
                                'No',d.RegdMtbkStatus) AS xNewMtbkStatus,
    IF(d.RegType = 'Fat', 
        (
            SELECT AccName 
            FROM tblfatora 
            INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraReso
            WHERE tblfatora.FatoraRef = d.RegRef
        )
        ,NULL) AS xReso,
    IF(d.RegType = 'Fat', 
        (
            SELECT AccName
            FROM tblfatora
            INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraCustomer
            WHERE tblfatora.FatoraRef = d.RegRef
        )
        ,NULL) AS xCus,
    IF(d.RegType = 'Fat', 
        (
            SELECT AccName
            FROM tblfatora
            INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblfatora.FatoraDriver
            WHERE tblfatora.FatoraRef = d.RegRef
        )
        ,NULL) AS xDriver,
    IF(d.RegType = 'Fat', 
        (
            SELECT FatoraQuan
            FROM tblfatora
            WHERE tblfatora.FatoraRef = d.RegRef
        )
        ,NULL) AS xQuan,
    IF(d.RegType = 'Fat', 
        (
            SELECT FatoraPurPrice
            FROM tblfatora
            WHERE tblfatora.FatoraRef = d.RegRef
        )
        ,NULL) AS xPurPrice,
    IF(d.RegType = 'Fat', 
        (
            SELECT FatoraSalePrice
            FROM tblfatora
            WHERE tblfatora.FatoraRef = d.RegRef
        )
        ,NULL) AS xSalePrice,
    (@acc:= d.RegdAccID) AS xacc
                            
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.RegDate, 
        a.RegID, 
        a.RegRef, 
        a.RegType,
        b.RegdID, 
        b.RegdAccID, 
        b.RegdM1, 
        b.RegdD1, 
        b.RegdM2, 
        b.RegdD2, 
        b.RegdNo,
        b.RegdMtbkRaseed, 
        b.RegdMtbkStatus, 
        b.RegdMtbkNotes,
        n.AccName
    FROM tblregs2 b
    INNER JOIN tblregs1 a ON b.RegRef = a.RegRef
    INNER JOIN tblaccounts n ON n.AccID = b.RegdAccID     
    WHERE (b.RegdM2>0 or b.RegdD2>0)
) d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ss := 0) cc
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @acc := 0) aa
ORDER BY 
    d.RegdAccID,
    d.RegDate,                                
    d.RegID,
    d.RegdID
```

my code to fill the datatable:

```vb
Dim xDa As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim xCmd As MySqlCommand
Dim MyVar_Dt_Main As New DataTable


xCmd = New MySqlCommand(MyVar_SqlStr_Main, Conn)
xDa = New MySqlDataAdapter(xCmd)
xDa.Fill(MyVar_Dt_Main)
xDa.Dispose()
xCmd.Dispose()
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think what you're looking for is: **xCmd.CommandTimeout = 500**

Comment: There is no practical reason why you should display 20k records at any given time to a user. This is a fundamental design flaw. You should consider paginated queries.

Comment: @David could you please tell me how I can use paginated queries in MySQL and vb.net

Comment: @NickAbbot thank you so much, it worked, could you please add it as answer?

Comment: This is poor practice. You may have 20,000 valid results, but **there is no good reason to display them in a datagrid**. People have _**formally studied this**_, such that we know single human beings are not able to effectively process more than ~1800 items in the same list. Find a way to further filter the data first.

Comment: Also, what version of MySql? If it's 8.0 or later, you should be able to re-write using a lateral join to make it **MUCH** faster and simpler. It can basically combine all those extra nested queries near the end of the `SELECT` list into _one_ single lateral join... you only have to write out the nested query once, and the server only needs to execute it once per row. Right now, it needs to execute all six nested queries once per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is: xCmd.CommandTimeout = 500